# How to Reset react-native-picker-select on form submit using formik inReact Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using Formik and react-native-picker-select, I can reset text and number fields after submission but can not able to reset picker-select. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reseted value for `react-native-picker-select` is null.

So you need to create a state that stores the current value of the picker and when you want to reset it, set it to null.

The secret here is set the `value={state variable}` parameter, so that the picker updates every time that the state is also updated. The `state variable` is updated with `onValueChange`.

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [pickerValue, setPickerValue] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <RNPickerSelect
        onValueChange={v => setPickerValue(v)}
        value={pickerValue}
        items={[
          {label: 'Football', value: 'football'},
          {label: 'Baseball', value: 'baseball'},
          {label: 'Hockey', value: 'hockey'},
        ]}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setPickerValue(null)}>
        <Text>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: This isn't using formik though. If this is the marked answer, the question should be changed.